# How do you set the default text size in Gimp 2.8 for Mac OSX Mountain Lion?

Tags: gimp, text

I am using Gimp 2.8 for Mac OS X, and I would like to change the default text size from 18 pt to 36 pt, so that I don't have to highlight the text and manually change every time I create a new text box. Even after selecting "Save tool options on exit" from the Preferences menu, the font size still goes back to 18 points when I create a new text box.

However I cannot figure out how to do that. All of the tutorials that I can find online appear to be for a Linux version, that looks like it has a different UI. Also, I have seen some answers that suggest there is a ".gimprc" file that can be edited, that has those settings in it. However, I cannot find any such file on my system. I think this may be because I downloaded the .dmg, which said to just open it and drag the executable into the applications folder, and didn't run any kind of installer that would have created the configuration files.

What is the correct way to set the default text size?

Answer (score 15):

I figured out how to do it! The reason that it wasn't saving the tool options even though I had selected "save tool options on exit" was because I was changing the font size on the controls that come up when you click in the image to create a new text box. This is just the controls for that text box, it isn't the actual tool options.

To change the actual tool options you have to DOUBLE click the text tool icon (the big "A") in the Toolbox. This brings up the actual tool options, where you can edit and save the options.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - gimp 2.10.28 on macos12.  Set fontsize 12 in both tool option and control for text box, saved tool options from the toolbox menu and preferences-save tool options (after unticking save on exit for both tool options and  input devices) , nada